# Objective C - NSOutputStream events arriving with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tcp, nsstream

I'm scheduling stream objects on run loops, and the server retrieves the correct information etc, however after dispatching requests to write to the NSOutputStream I am receiving events a lot later than expected, screwing up control flow. I handle events using the following method from the [NSStreamDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSStreamDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream*)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
```

I am calling the query as follows, and the events aren't received until the loops have been exit :

```
for (NSMutableArray* objs in allObjs) {

    for (Obj* o in objs) {

        [self searchQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ foo", o.bar]];
    }
}
```

I tried creating a global variable that flags whether the most recent dispatched event has been processed, this is looped over before iterating again in the inner for loop, but runs indefinitely.

How should I correctly wait for each result from the queries before iterating again in the inner for loop?

Thanks in advance! :)

Side note : 
My iOS app is using TCP sockets to communicate with a server I have written in Python, following this [tutorial by Cesare Rocchi](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server).

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to understand fully what you're trying to do. Are you saying that responding to stream events isn't sufficient to maintain control flow?

Comment: I'm saying no event is received until after leaving the for loops! Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: That would make sense. Program flow won't reach your `-stream:handleEvent:` method until you get out of your loop.

Comment: Why so? Is it not an independent asynchronous event?

Comment: It is, but you'll never get it while you're in a `for` loop that keeps your application from running its event loop. (Assuming that you scheduled your streams on the main event loop.)